# Making a Rails app only accessible if authenticated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm trying to implement a login screen into my Rails app. This does not give create or search up an account for the user, but rather just checks to see if they know the password.

There is only one password, and only those that know it should have access to the application.

I successfully have the application redirecting users to the login screen if they try to access any page, but how would set the user as authenticated so that I don't continue to redirect them back to login?

Comment: You will need to store that piece in the session. Are you using devise or any other authentication library?

Comment: I'm not using an authentication library. Can I use the rails session store if I'm not authenticating them with an account? How would I keep track if they don't have a specific user_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can record in the session the fact that they have "logged in" (aka knew the password). You can do so by doing something similar to your controller that receives the form:

```
if params[:password] == ENV['YOUR_GLOBAL_PASSWORD']
  session[:authenticated] = true 
end
```

Then add a before_filter to the parts of the app you want to protect:

```
before_filter :authenticate

def authenticate
  unless session[:authenticated]
    render head :forbidden
    return false
  end
end
```

I would strongly recommend you to just use [HTTP Basic Auth](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html).

Comment: Awesome, I got it working just fine. I would use HTTP Basic Auth, but it's so ugly. Is there a way to link it to a login page?

Comment: It is implemented as a middleware so it's not usually a great way to hook it. You can find a similar question in regards to that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577139/trigger-basic-http-auth-from-within-middleware